# angular 10 upgrade - 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin vendor.js attach SourceMapKilled

Tags: angular

I'm trying to upgrade to Angular 10, and in running "npm run-script build" which is just calling "ng build --output-path dist" I keep getting an error code of 137. Log details are shown below.

Any idea on how to debug this further?

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [
> '/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/node', 1 verbose cli
> '/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/npm', 1 verbose cli
> 'run-script', 1 verbose cli   'build' ] 2 info using npm@6.10.2 3 info
> using node@v10.15.0 4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build',
> 'postbuild' ] 5 info lifecycle fantasy-prime@0.0.0~prebuild:
> fantasy-prime@0.0.0 6 info lifecycle fantasy-prime@0.0.0~build:
> fantasy-prime@0.0.0 7 verbose lifecycle fantasy-prime@0.0.0~build:
> unsafe-perm in lifecycle true 8 verbose lifecycle
> fantasy-prime@0.0.0~build: PATH:
> /home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/.bin:/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
> 9 verbose lifecycle fantasy-prime@0.0.0~build: CWD:
> /home/cabox/workspace 10 silly lifecycle fantasy-prime@0.0.0~build:
> Args: [ '-c', 'ng build --output-path dist' ] 11 silly lifecycle
> fantasy-prime@0.0.0~build: Returned: code: 137  signal: null 12 info
> lifecycle fantasy-prime@0.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script 13
> verbose stack Error: fantasy-prime@0.0.0 build: `ng build --output-path dist` 13 verbose stack Exit status 137 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.
> (/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:326:16)
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13) 13
> verbose stack     at ChildProcess.
> (/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13) 13
> verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16) 13
> verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:251:5) 14 verbose pkgid fantasy-prime@0.0.0
> 15 verbose cwd /home/cabox/workspace 16 verbose Linux
> 2.6.32-042stab140.4
>
> 17 verbose argv "/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/node"
> "/home/cabox/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/npm" "run-script" "build"
> 18 verbose node v10.15.0 19 verbose npm  v6.10.2 20 error code
> ELIFECYCLE 21 error errno 137 22 error fantasy-prime@0.0.0 build: `ng build --output-path dist` 22 error Exit status 137 23 error Failed at
> the fantasy-prime@0.0.0 build script. 23 error This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. 24
> verbose exit [ 137, true ]

I'm using the following versions of Angular components:

```
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1001.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1001.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1001.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1001.1
@angular-devkit/core              10.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.1.1
@angular/cdk                      10.2.1
@angular/flex-layout              10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/language-service         8.1.3
@angular/material                 10.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                  10.1.1
@schematics/angular               10.1.1
@schematics/update                0.1001.1
ng-packagr                        10.1.0
rxjs                              6.6.3
typescript                        4.0.2
webpack                           4.44.1
```